Enforce only one row 'active' in Sharepoint list
I have a Sharepoint list with items, and one of the columns is a Yes/No column named 'Active'.
I want to enforce that only one item can have Active = Yes at any given moment. 
So if a user checks this box for an item, all the other items have this column set to 'No', automatically.
How would I go about to achieve this?
I looked into 'unique values' but that doesn't apply to boolean columns.
Cheers,
CJ

please check my below answer

did my answer fix your issue?

did my below answer fixed your issue? if so, can you accept it, so it will be beneficial for others?

@CJ Scholten Defining unique values will not work for you, even if the column type support this (for example if you replace your Yes/No column with choice column), as you will also not be able to have multiple items with No values.
What you can do is to create an automated power automate flow that only runs when you set the Boolean to Yes, you can use this trigger condition:-
@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Active'],true)

then use the Get Items action >> to get all items which have their Active = True and update them to false. of course, you need to exclude the current item based on the ID. this will 99% work for you, unless you have many users accessing the list and updating the items at the same time. to handle this, create a view which only show the items with Active = True, and check if you will get more than one item at a time.
Regards
